# how could convert radzen scheduler from gregorian date to shamsi date

Tags: components, scheduler, persian-calendar, radzen

[image]Radzen scheduler use Gregorian date time format for showing Calender.how I could convert this format of Calender to Shamsi ?

Answer (score 0):

FIRST of all I used radzen source code  from github and I maked some changes to the schedule by getting the first day of the month by using md.persiandatetime library and withe same library I changed labels of the dates to show persian dates but in the background all dates are  gregorian dates